# Cannot find symbol class interface

Tags: java

soo... it is said that java cannot find symbol..

i've already included the class Interface on Interface.java but somehow it said it cant find symbol

these are the code of Interface.java

```
package com.gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Interface {
    public Interface() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("click to close");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("click that button to exit");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(300, 300, 100, 300));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("gui test");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
}
```

and these are the code from Main.java

```
    package com.gui;

        public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args){
                new Interface();
        }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a `main()` method in your `Interface` class?

Comment: The problem is not reproducible, the code can be compiled. Please [edit] your question to include the full source code and the full compile error message. Also make sure you have recompiled the classes after you have changed them.

Comment: Which symbol cannot be found? Please provide the full error message

Comment: this is the source code
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OS4lQlEcOtG0qS1ZlZbskFBlXf609A1c?usp=sharing
and this is the full error message

C:\Users\g15\IdeaProjects\GuiTEST\src\com\gui\Main.java:6:21
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Interface
  location: class com.gui.Main

Comment: @Shuu Please add your code to the question itself, not on an external site (or in a comment).

Comment: The code is already in the question

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the opened the project using Intellij and got the same error as you.

I managed to fix it by changing the `Interface` class to `Interface1` (using `SHIFT + F6` on `Interface`).

[image]

I uploaded the zip to here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y_-7juqPtJKdUeWdLhRCvWMFLHYagVwQ/view?usp=sharing
(I hope you it's indeed accessible)